# Dialogflow - Add followupEvent after a given delay

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to add a series of responses inside an intent handler and set a timer of 20 minutes which will trigger(at its end) a followup event.

So here is what I've tried:

```
agent.add(response_1);
//...
agent.add(response_n);
setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Setting follow up event")
        agent.setFollowupEvent('20_MINUTES_PASSED');
      }, 1200000);
```

Even though the log was displayed, my function execution stopped before it. I have checked the logs and I saw the message "Function execution took 26 ms, finished with status code: 200" displayed before "Setting follow up event".

I know that each function has a 3-5 sec timeout and I understand this is why the function finished its execution, but I cannot figure out how to trigger that event after those 20 minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with this idea: Cloud functions aren't meant to run for that long, you would have to use either a real server or some scheduling service for this. However, Dialogflow doesn't let you do this anyway, webhook requests time out after a few seconds. If you haven't send a response by then the agent will tell the user that your service is unavailable. You can also not initiate a new session without the users explicit request to do so, presumably because developers would quickly abuse this for spam etc. There is thus no way to trigger an event after 20 minutes.

The closest to what you are looking for are probably [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications), but they are very limited compared to follow up events.